# How to document undefined precompilation flags

Tags: c, undefined, doxygen

I have C code I want to document using doxygen. The C code is a block of code, which can be taken in by different applications. At compile time, these applications alter the functionality of the block of code by defining specific macros (or by *not* defining them).

For example, take this file, `block.c`:

```
int Block_DoPlus(int x, int y)
{
#if defined(DO_EXTRAPLUS)
    return x + y + y;
#else
    return x + y;
#endif
}

int Block_DoMinus(int x, int y)
{
#if defined(DO_EXTRAMINUS)
return x - y - y;
#else
return x - y;
#endif
}
```

What is the best way to document these undefined precompilation flags `DO_EXTRAPLUS` and `DO_EXTRAMINUS`?

- I want them to look identical to other flags and tokens that are nicely documented
- I want to equally allow users of my code to conditionally define callbacks, and I see only `#undef` as a reasonable option for that.
- I want to use defines instead of getters/setters to minimize code (think big).

---

**Option 1**: `block.h` - **does not work**; `DO_EXTRAPLUS` and `DO_EXTRAMINUS` do not show in the generated html

```
#ifndef __BLOCK_H__
#define __BLOCK_H__
/** @defgroup BLOCK A block of code
 * gcc this code with -dDO_EXTRAPLUS and/or -dDO_EXTRAMINUS
 * @{
 */

/** Does extra plus */
#ifndef DO_EXTRAPLUS
#   undef DO_EXTRAPLUS
#endif

/** Does extra minus */
#ifndef DO_EXTRAMINUS
#   undef DO_EXTRAMINUS
#endif

/** Does plus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoPlus(int x, int y);

/** Does minus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoMinus(int x, int y);
#endif /** @} */
```

---

**Option 2**: `block.h` - **works**, but looks stupid in code

```
#ifndef __BLOCK_H__
#define __BLOCK_H__
/** @defgroup BLOCK A block of code
 * gcc this code with -dDO_EXTRAPLUS and/or -dDO_EXTRAMINUS
 * @{
 */

/** Does extra plus */
#ifndef DO_EXTRAPLUS
#   define DO_EXTRAPLUS
#   undef DO_EXTRAPLUS
#endif

/** Does extra minus */
#ifndef DO_EXTRAMINUS
#   define DO_EXTRAMINUS
#   undef DO_EXTRAMINUS
#endif

/** Does plus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoPlus(int x, int y);

/** Does minus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoMinus(int x, int y);

#endif /** @} */
```

**Option 3**: `block.h` - **works**, but looks stupid in html file, plus you can't reference `DO_EXTRAPLUS` later using `::` (or `#`), only with `\ref`

```
#ifndef __BLOCK_H__
#define __BLOCK_H__
/** @defgroup BLOCK My fancy block of code
 * gcc this code with -dDO_EXTRAPLUS and/or -dDO_EXTRAMINUS
 * 
 * @anchor DO_EXTRAPLUS
 * @par #define DO_EXTRAPLUS
 *  Does plus
 *  
 * @anchor DO_EXTRAMINUS
 * @par #define DO_EXTRAMINUS
 *  Does minus
 * @{
 */

/** Does plus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoPlus(int x, int y);

/** Does minus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoMinus(int x, int y);

#endif /** @} */
```

---

**Option 4**: ???

Comment: Unrelated: Move the `#endif` before the `}` and don't have more `#endif`s than `#if`s.

Comment: Unrelated: There is a typo in your first code fragment - two functions with the same name.

Comment: Two 'unrelated's fixed. Tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found:

**Option 4**: `block.h` - **works**, looks good both in code and in html

```
#ifndef __BLOCK_H__
#define __BLOCK_H__
/** @defgroup BLOCK A block of code
 * @{
 */

/* Flags below are undefined by default.
 * They are wrapped in a DOXYGEN precompilation flag to enable
 * documenting them properly.
 */
#ifdef __DOXYGEN__
#error This block of code may not be parsed using gcc.

/** Does extra plus */
#define DO_EXTRAPLUS When defined, changes behavior of Block_DoPlus

/** Does extra minus */
#define DO_EXTRAMINUS When defined, changes behavior of Block_DoMinus

#endif

/** Does plus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoPlus(int x, int y);

/** Does minus
 * @param x : x is ickx
 * @param y : y is why
 */
int Block_DoMinus(int x, int y);

#endif /** @} */
```

**Plus**, add `__DOXYGEN__` as a predefined macro in your *doxyfile*

- The flags can be referenced using `::` (or `#`)
- The flags are documented equally as other tokens
- The text after the define is parsed and recognized tokens are linked
- The `#error` directive and the non-doxygen comment gives a clear explanation of the construct

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for option 0: don't use compiler flags for configuration. Use global variables (or, better yet, variables in an configuration object) instead.

- Compiler flags are difficult to document, as you've discovered.
- Compiler flags cannot be changed at runtime.
- Compiler flags are shared across an executable. There is no (easy) way to have an application where one part of the application uses your code with one set of compiler flags and another part uses different flags.
- Compiler flags are incompatible with building code as a library. (I mean, you *can* build the code as a library, but you have to pick which flags to use when it's built. Consumers of the library have no choice in the matter.)
- Compiler flags are incompatible with code testing:

  - Most testing frameworks assume that your code can be compiled once, then tested by calling it in different ways -- this becomes impossible when parts of your code are only accessible when built with certain compiler flags.
  - If your code has even a moderate number of compiler flags, testing all combinations becomes impossible. You end up in a situation where certain sets of flags may never be tested, and may cause unexpected behavior (or even compilation failures!) due to unexpected interactions between different conditionally enabled blocks of code.

Comment: Compiler flags cannot be changed at runtime: that's a plus for me. In my case, I'm writing code in a rather stringent environment: my Flash is 32kB and is to be used for more than just storing the firmware. Consider the situation where I might offer the choice between two compression algorithms. I most certainly don't want to drag along 2kB of code which will never be executed.

Comment: Compiler flags are incompatible with building code as a library: correct. If there is code delivery involved towards different customer, _and_ the code is binary only, there will be a lot of compiling beforehand. The choice here implies we've decided to deliver full sources to the application developers.

Comment: Compiler flags are incompatible with code testing: not correct. It makes it tedious, but certainly not impossible. We're doing it. Testing all combinations is almost equally impossible if you use getters and setters. Consider a block of code with 10 getters/setters, each having 2 choices (bool). How many test setups try out the 1024 different combinations? Defines have the advantage that you can check things at precompilation time. I prefer a compilation error to a configuration error at runtime.